# PHPExcel Duplicate data cleaning

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a assignment to create an application that reads excel file data and inserts into database, but the excel file can contain duplicate data so before it is inserted into database it needs to check out whether it has duplicate data?

How is this possible to do with PHPExcel?

Comment: How are you adding the excel data to the db table?  Are you just uploading the file or actually parsing the file and adding it to your db table?

Comment: I am parsing the file. Anyway, i have managed to avoid duplicate data by using php/mysql combination. Right now i am sometimes facing problems when  the app reads empty rows from excel file and inserts into database.

Comment: PHPExcel isn't going to do that for you, PHPExcel is simply a library for reading/writing data from Excel spreadsheets.... it's up to your application what you do with that data

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this function to check whether given **column** has duplicate data (and also you can choose wheter to ignore empty cells or not). You can easily extend this function to work with whole rows.

```
function hasDuplicatedValues($objPHPExcel, $column = 'A', $ignoreEmptyCells = false) {
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $cells = array();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCell($column . $row->getRowIndex())->getValue();
        if (($ignoreEmptyCells == false) | (empty($cell) == false)) {
            $cells[] = $cell;
        }
    }

    return count(array_unique($cells)) < count($cells);
}
```

If you would like to remove duplicated data, you can try to modify this code: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/452531/phpexcel-removing-duplicates#post1962349 or search/ask Stack Overflow.